# Ubuntu server does not detect DHCPv4 on virt-manager

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

[image]

I am installing ubuntu server on virt-manager but it can not detect DHCPv4. I click continue without network then it gives me error below when I **install** or **update** something

```
failed to fetch http //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/inrelease temporary failure resolving
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360490/how-to-configure-basic-network-in-virt-manager